# Java method cast Arraylist of childclass to parentclass and reverse

Tags: java, inheritance, arraylist, methods

I have a Parent Class Item and multiple child classes itemA, itemB etc.

Now I want to have a method which takes 2 ArrayLists of the same classtype (for example itemA,itemA) and map the items based on a method in the parent class( so my idea was to make a method which takes in 2 Arraylists of the parent class so it accepts Arraylists of the child classes which were cast to the parent class.

Heres how the method should look like:

```
HashMap<Item,Item> mapping(ArrayList<Item> prop1, ArrayList<Item> prop2)
{
    //Content of the method not that important
}
```

And I should be able to call the method with the Arraylists of the child classes like

```
Arraylist<ItemA> list1 = ...;
ArrayList<ItemA> list2 = ...;
mapping(list1, list2);
```

But Apparently you cannot cast between Arraylists that easily. My only idea was to write 3 seperate methods for the 3 classes itemA, itemB, itemC. Does anyone have a better idea?

Comment: Why don't you use a generic method with a bound on the type parameter?

Comment: By the way: declare `List<...>`, `Map<...>`, interface based variables.

Comment: @JoopEggen could you elaborate?

Comment: It is customary; you will see it everywhere - for good reasons. It is called _programming against interfaces_. The implementing class does not influence the usage, so you might change the implementation. More important: methods are more general when accepting a List parameter instead of an ArrayList. And as return result of a method you can return any suitable List, like `List.emptyList()`, `Collections.singletonList(value)`, or whatever.

Comment: And having several implementations at disposal is nice aspect of the language: a Map can be HashMap, or sorted on key TreeMap, or sorted on insertion LinkedHashMap. Compare this with a scripting language, where you have one moloch.

Comment: Ah thank you already suspected something in that direction :)

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this:

```
<T extends Item> HashMap<T, T> mapping(ArrayList<T> prop1, 
                                       ArrayList<T> prop2) {
    // ...
}
```

then

```
Arraylist<ItemA> list1 = ...;
ArrayList<ItemA> list2 = ...;

HashMap<ItemA, ItemA> map = mapping(list1, list2);
```

Note that the type system will ensure that the same type (`ItemA`, `ItemB`, whatever) is used for both the arguments and the result.

---

> Apparently you cannot cast between Arraylists that easily.

Correct.  There is no subtype relationship between `ArrayList<Item>` and `ArrayList<ItemA>` etcetera

> My only idea was to write 3 separate methods for the 3 classes itemA, itemB, itemC.

The 3 methods would have to have different names or be in different classes.  You will find that Java won't let you declare

```
HashMap<Item,Item> mapping(ArrayList<Item> prop1, 
                           ArrayList<Item> prop2)
```

and

```
HashMap<ItemA,ItemA> mapping(ArrayList<ItemA> prop1, 
                             ArrayList<ItemA> prop2)
```

in the same class / interface.  Method signatures must be distinguishable [*after type erasure*](https://www.baeldung.com/java-type-erasure)!

Comment: But wait... you wouldnt be able to declare those 3 methods? In my understanding that would be just be overloading functions? What do you mean with type erasure?

Comment: 1)  Overloaded methods need to be distinct after type erasure.  If you don't believe me ... try it.  2)  See https://www.baeldung.com/java-type-erasure for an explanation of type erasure.

Answer (score 0):

```java
<T extends Item> HashMap<T,T> mapping(ArrayList<T> prop1, ArrayList<T> prop2)
{
    //Content of the method not that important
}
```

Comment: Ah thank you I didnt know you that T in a generic method could be a child class and thus access those methods :)

Comment: Can you add an explanation to your answer? As a newbie it might be hard to understand the solution without the context

Comment: Its called a generic method. You can read more about it here https://www.baeldung.com/java-generics